# Cells won't be created in a TableView

Tags: android, tableview

I'm using this library to create a Tableview: https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

I can create the Corner, Row Headers and Column Headers.
However, it won't create the cells. 
Here you can see my Adapter. My Layouts and Holders are the same as in the sample project.

I also get this Error:

```
02-28 16:34:02.954 2676-2676/de.tk.annapp W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by com.evrencoskun.tableview.adapter.recyclerview.CellRecyclerView{6b3989d VFED..... ......I. 0,98-0,98 #62} during layout: running second layout pass
```

My Adapter

```
public class TVAdapterTimetable extends AbstractTableAdapter<ColumnHeader, RowHeader, Cell> {

public TVAdapterTimetable(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateCellViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Get cell xml layout
    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.table_view_cell_layout,
            parent, false);

    System.out.println("Create Cell View Holder...");

    // Create a Custom ViewHolder for a Cell item.
    return new CellViewHolder(layout);
}

@Override
public void onBindCellViewHolder(AbstractViewHolder holder, Object cellItemModel, int
        columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
    Cell cell = (Cell) cellItemModel;

    System.out.println("Set Attributes for the Cell");

    // Get the holder to update cell item text
    CellViewHolder viewHolder = (CellViewHolder) holder;
    viewHolder.cell_textview.setText(cell.getData().toString());

    // If your TableView should have auto resize for cells & columns.
    // Then you should consider the below lines. Otherwise, you can ignore them.

    // It is necessary to remeasure itself.
    viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams().width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    viewHolder.cell_textview.requestLayout();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateColumnHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    // Get Column Header xml Layout
    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout
            .table_view_column_header_layout, parent, false);

    // Create a ColumnHeader ViewHolder
    return new ColumnHeaderViewHolder(layout, getTableView());
}

@Override
public void onBindColumnHeaderViewHolder(AbstractViewHolder holder, Object columnHeaderItemModel, int
        position) {
    ColumnHeader columnHeader = (ColumnHeader) columnHeaderItemModel;

    // Get the holder to update cell item text
    ColumnHeaderViewHolder columnHeaderViewHolder = (ColumnHeaderViewHolder) holder;
    columnHeaderViewHolder.column_header_textview.setText(columnHeader.getData().toString());

    // If your TableView should have auto resize for cells & columns.
    // Then you should consider the below lines. Otherwise, you can ignore them.

    // It is necessary to remeasure itself.
    columnHeaderViewHolder.column_header_container.getLayoutParams().width = LinearLayout
            .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    columnHeaderViewHolder.column_header_textview.requestLayout();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateRowHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    // Get Row Header xml Layout
    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout
            .table_view_row_header_layout, parent, false);

    // Create a Row Header ViewHolder
    return new RowHeaderViewHolder(layout);
}

@Override
public void onBindRowHeaderViewHolder(AbstractViewHolder holder, Object rowHeaderItemModel, int
        position) {
    RowHeader rowHeader = (RowHeader) rowHeaderItemModel;

    // Get the holder to update row header item text
    RowHeaderViewHolder rowHeaderViewHolder = (RowHeaderViewHolder) holder;
    rowHeaderViewHolder.row_header_textview.setText(rowHeader.getData().toString());
}


@Override
public View onCreateCornerView() {
    // Get Corner xml layout
    return LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.table_view_corner_layout, null);
}

@Override
public int getColumnHeaderItemViewType(int columnPosition) {
    // The unique ID for this type of column header item
    // If you have different items for Cell View by X (Column) position,
    // then you should fill this method to be able create different
    // type of CellViewHolder on "onCreateCellViewHolder"
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getRowHeaderItemViewType(int rowPosition) {
    // The unique ID for this type of row header item
    // If you have different items for Row Header View by Y (Row) position,
    // then you should fill this method to be able create different
    // type of RowHeaderViewHolder on "onCreateRowHeaderViewHolder"
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getCellItemViewType(int columnPosition) {
    // The unique ID for this type of cell item
    // If you have different items for Cell View by X (Column) position,
    // then you should fill this method to be able create different
    // type of CellViewHolder on "onCreateCellViewHolder"
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: why don't you create an issue on Github. https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView/issues/new